# Highcharts: Ensure y-Axis 0 value is at chart bottom

Tags: highcharts

I'm outputting a series of highcharts on a page. In some instances, all data for the specified time period may come back with 0 values.

In such a case, the chart looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/charliegriefer/KM2Jx/1/

There is only 1 y-Axis label, 0, and it's in the middle of the chart.

I'd like to force that 0 value for the y-Axis to be at the bottom of the chart, which would be consistent with other charts on the page that do have data.

Have tried various yAxis properties, such as "min: 0", "minPadding: 0", "maxPadding: 0", "startOnTick: true".

Seems it should be pretty straightforward, but I'm at a loss :(

Relevant yAxis code:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0, 
    minPadding: 0, 
    startOnTick: true, 
    title: {
        text: ""
    }
},
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Only way I could get it to show it "correctly" was by also providing an yAxis `max` value. I think this is a HighCharts issue when you provide no data elements with a y-value. It draws the best chart it thinks it can.

Comment: I tried to update the fiddle with an xAxis max value, but that didn't work for me. The chart rendered the same. Appreciate the answer tho. What worked is outlined for me in a separate answer.

Comment: Ah yes. That does address it. Very cool. Still need to do the pre-processing for my situation, but that'd be the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I do agree that the HighCharts library needs to be smarter about it.

Comment: I was surprised with this behavior while updating from 2.1.3 where there was no such problem.

Answer (score 43):

I've found another (and very simple) solution:

You can set y-axis `minRange` property:

```
yAxis: {
    ...
    minRange : 0.1
}
```

This makes Highcharts render yAxis min and max values when all data is 0.

UPDATE:

Highcharts 4.1.9 fix also needs:

```
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                softThreshold: false
            }
        }
```

[updated js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynWLK/27/)

Comment: I had to combine this with min as well but this works great! This is by far the best answer as it doesn't require any preprocessing.

Comment: minRange + softThreshold works perfectly, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The 4.1.9 update didn't work for me, if you're using newer Highcharts use the softMax value: `yAxis: {
    softMax: 10
}`

Answer (score 5):

I had also posted this to the HighCharts forum, where I got a response that seems to work. Unfortunately, it will involve me doing some pre-processing of the data prior to rendering the charts in order to check for all "0" data values... but it'll work. Just wish there was something more "built-in" to HighCharts.

So after summing up the "y" values, if I get 0, the y-axis properties should look like this:

```
yAxis: {
    minPadding: 0, 
    maxPadding: 0,         
    min: 0, 
    max:1,
    showLastLabel:false,
    tickInterval:1,
    title: {
            text: ""
    }
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/KM2Jx/2/

The keys seem to be the "max" and "showLastLabel" properties.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fix I came up with that doesn't require any preprocessing of the data and just let highcharts do it, like it used to before the update. http://jsfiddle.net/QEK3x/

```
if(chart.yAxis[0].dataMax === 0)
{
   chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 5);
}
```

You only need to check the first series axis, as if the first one is not 0 then the problem won't occur. I might submit a pull request for this to high-charts, though I kinda feel like they intended for this functionality for some reason.

Comment: This works, but will cause the chart to re-draw. If you don't want that to happen, it seems like you need to pre-process the data to find out if you need to set a `max` value.

Comment: This logic worked for me. I had to slightly adjust it as follows but same principle:                                                                                                     if (highChartConfig.series[0].data.dataMax == 0) {
                    highChartConfig.yAxis[0].max = 50;
                }

Answer (score 3):

Since Highcharts 5.0.1, you can also use softMax.

> **softMax: Number**
>   A soft maximum for the axis. If the series data maximum is greater than this, the axis will stay at this maximum, but if the series data maximum is higher, the axis will flex to show all data.

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    softMax: 100,
    ...
}
```

Here is an example with a column chart : http://jsfiddle.net/84LLsepj/

Note that currently, in Highcharts 5.0.7, it doesn't seem to be working for all types of charts. As you can see in [this other jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/th1e6tfm/), it doesn't work with line chart.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "min" option

```
yAxis: {
   min: 0
}
```

Comment: this wont work if you have negative values. they wont show.

Answer (score 0):

For Highcharts 5.x.x, you should be able to just specify:

```
yAxis: {
  softMin: 0,
  softMax: 1,
};
```

This won't work for line chart, which requires that you also set `minRange` in the same config object as above. Experiment with different values, since defining for example `minRange: 6`, created a range on yAxis between 0 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

minRange : 1 or whatever you feel so to be displayed in fractions of
  softMax : 100 or whatever you feel so

[image: Result]

```
yAxis: {
         minRange : 1,
         softMax: 100
       }
```