# highcharts.js push line to the bottom of the charts when y values are all 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

when the values of y axis are all 0, the 0 line runs at the middle of the chart which is not very good-looking. I want to push the 0 line to the bottom of the chart. I tried the solution on this post but not working

[Highcharts: Ensure y-Axis 0 value is at chart bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991873/highcharts-ensure-y-axis-0-value-is-at-chart-bottom)

http://jsfiddle.net/tZayD/58/

```
$(function () {
        $('#container5').highcharts({
      chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat']       
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {text: ''},
                    min:0
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Total Appts',
                    data: [0,0,0,0,0,0]
                }, {
                    name: 'Confirmed',
                    data: [0,0,0,0,0,0]
                }, {
                    name: 'no-shows',
                    data: [0,0,0,0,0,0]
                }]
            });          
    })
```

Comment: I just tried it with your code setting yAxis.max to 10 and it moved the 0 point down. What is not working?

Comment: minRange doesn't work. yeah, setting max value work. Can I get rid of the grid line as well? I just want to have a 0 line at the bottom and nothing on top? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the 0 "yValue" appear at the bottom of a chart instead of floating in the middle of the chart space you need to set the `yAxis.max` value as well. Set it to some arbitrary value that is within you expected value range.

To remove the gridlines and just have the 0 "yValue" grid you can set the `gridLineWidth` to 0.

Sample:

```
        yAxis: {
            title: {text: ''},
            min:0,
            max: 10,
            gridLineWidth: 0
        },
```